# How do you enable scp in libcurl when using with R?

Tags: r, rstudio, libcurl, rcurl

I am trying to use scp from within RStudio to directly access a remote log file. I can use scp from the command line and it works great. But within RStudio I get the following error:

Protocol "scp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

How can I enable scp?

I am using the curl and RCurl libraries with RStudio

Environment:
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin13.4.0
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0
status
major          3
minor          2.0
year           2015
month          04
day            16
svn rev        68180
language       R
version.string R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
nickname       Full of Ingredients

Comment: It looks like your installed libcurl might be missing some features and that you need to install another version. Search for the word `scp` in the [RCurl FAQ](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html), it has a paragraph addressing the issue.

Comment: Thank you jpw. How can it be that the shell can access rcp correctly but RStudio and R cannot? Does shell not use the same libraries?

Comment: It does, but the stock, pre-built binaries for RCurl (or the config in the locally compiled ones) may not have that built in. You may be able to follow some of [these steps](http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/adding-sftp-support-to-curl) to accomplish this, but it will mean you will always have to maintain a custom version of RCurl vs use the stock binary OS X downloads from CRAN.

Comment: Keep an eye out on https://github.com/jeroenooms/ssh though as Jeroen may add full scp support to that pkg.

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours to resolve this. This link solved my issue.

Reinstall curl following this link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128780/how-to-build-the-latest-curl-from-sources-to-allow-downloading-files-via-sftp

Then, reinstall RCurl:

```
install.packages("RCurl",type="source")
```